# How to limit scroll speed of a Scrollview?

Tags: react-native, react-scroll, react-flatlist

I have a FlatList with like 300 cells and I want to limit the momentum of a scroll. On ios if you have a large list you can exponentially increase the speed at which it is scrolling through the list by just consecutively doing fast scrolls. This is what i want to disable/ make it a lot less. I dont want to disable momentum scroll, I just want to make it so that you cant keep increasing that momentum.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called `decelerationRate`,

```
<ScrollView decelerationRate={0.5}>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yes but this is not limitting the momentum, just slowing it down faster. I want to limit it as you can still get very fast momentum even with this.